# MGCP protocol: Where is the EndpointID in the package?

Tags: protocols

In [RFC 3435](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3435#section-2.3.5) CreateConnection request described as a `EndpointID` parameter dependent:

```
         ReturnCode,
         [ConnectionId,]
         [SpecificEndPointId,]
         [LocalConnectionDescriptor,]
         [SecondEndPointId,]
         [SecondConnectionId,]
         [PackageList]
         <-- CreateConnection(CallId,
                              EndpointId,
                              [NotifiedEntity,]
                              [LocalConnectionOptions,]
                              Mode,
                              [{RemoteConnectionDescriptor |
                              SecondEndpointId}, ]
                              [Encapsulated NotificationRequest,]
                              [Encapsulated EndpointConfiguration])
```

But protocol grammar have no that parameter:

```
ParameterValue = ("K"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [ResponseAck])
               / ("B"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [BearerInformation])
               / ("C"  ":" 0*(WSP)  CallId)
               / ("I"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [ConnectionId])
               / ("N"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [NotifiedEntity])
               / ("X"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [RequestIdentifier])
               / ("L"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [LocalConnectionOptions])
               / ("M"  ":" 0*(WSP)  ConnectionMode)
               / ("R"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [RequestedEvents])
               / ("S"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [SignalRequests])
               / ("D"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [DigitMap])
               / ("O"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [ObservedEvents])
               / ("P"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [ConnectionParameters])
               / ("E"  ":" 0*(WSP)  ReasonCode)
               / ("Z"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [SpecificEndpointID])
               / ("Z2" ":" 0*(WSP)  SecondEndpointID)
               / ("I2" ":" 0*(WSP)  SecondConnectionID)
               / ("F"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [RequestedInfo])
               / ("Q"  ":" 0*(WSP)  QuarantineHandling)
               / ("T"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [DetectEvents])
               / ("RM" ":" 0*(WSP)  RestartMethod)
               / ("RD" ":" 0*(WSP)  RestartDelay)
               / ("A"  ":" 0*(WSP)  [Capabilities])
               / ("ES" ":" 0*(WSP)  [EventStates])
               / ("PL" ":" 0*(WSP)  [PackageList])    ; Auditing only
               / ("MD" ":" 0*(WSP)  MaxMGCPDatagram)  ; Auditing only
               / (extensionParameter ":" 0*(WSP) [parameterString])
```

Also RFC is not contains description of this parameter.

How `EndpointID` parameter displaces in MGCP packet?

Can i get an example of using this parameter?